# Azure DevOps pipeline string split and foreach over the array

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have to create a pipeline and execute a series of tasks per each of my repositories.

So I created a job that fetch the repositories using the rest api [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0)
and then setting an output variable with all the urls in a csv format.

In another job I take this csv and do an split by an iterate over it like this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split

And the each expression instead of evaluate the expression is taking the expression itself as an string.

```
trigger: none

pool: 
  vmImage: windows-2022

stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
    - job: FetchRepositoriesJob
      displayName: Fetch repositories
      workspace:
        clean: all
      steps:
        - checkout: none

        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: FetchRepositoriesTask
          displayName: Fetch repositories
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # ... Code to fetch repositories and create a csv of the urls was omitted for brevety

              $csvRepositoriesUrl="https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/repo1,https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/repo2"
              
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=csvRepositoriesUrl;isOutput=true]$csvRepositoriesUrl"

    - job: MyOtherJob
      dependsOn: FetchRepositoriesJob
      condition: succeeded('FetchRepositoriesJob')
      workspace:
        clean: all
      variables:
        - name: repositories
          value: $[ dependencies.FetchRepositoriesJob.outputs['FetchRepositoriesTask.csvRepositoriesUrl'] ]
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        
        - powershell: Write-Host $(repositories)    # this task print "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/repo1,https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/repo2"

        - ${{ each repository in split(variables.repositories, ',')}}:
            - powershell: Write-Host ${{ repository }}   # but this task print: "$[ dependencies.FetchRepositoriesJob.outputs['FetchRepositoriesTask.csvRepositoriesUrl'] ]" 

            # here I would like to execute a series of task per each repository
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the expression `$[ dependencies.first.outputs['FetchRepositoriesTask.csvRepositoriesUrl'] ]` doesn't get evaluated when using the [Template expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax). As an alternative, you can use PowerShell [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.3)

```
- powershell: | 
    "$(repositories)" -split "," | ForEach {
      "Repo: $_"
    }
```